# Sets of finite measure satisfy $|\mu (A) −\mu (B)| \le \mu(A \triangle B)$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $(Ω,A,μ)$ be a measure space. If $A,B ∈ A$ are arbitrary sets satisfying $μ(A) < ∞$ or $μ(B) < ∞$, then $|μ(A) − μ(B)| ≤ μ(A △ B)$.

It is relatively easy to show if $A⊂B$. But since I can't assume that I am stuck. Please help :)

Comment: Hint:
$$
\mu(A) = \mu(B\cap A) + \mu(A\setminus B) \leq \mu(B) + \mu(A\Delta B)
$$

Comment: The title sin't supposed to replace the first line of your question. The statement is vacuously is true in $\sf ZFC$ as it can be written as $\forall A(A\in A\implies \text{something})$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that one of the $A$ is the $\sigma$-algebra... Probably meant to be written as $\mathcal{A}$.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by Prahlad Vaidyanathan in the comments is completely sufficient and elementary. Here is another approach, based on the observation $|1_A-1_B|=1_{A\Delta B}$. It follows that
$$|\mu(A)-\mu(B)|=\left|\int 1_A d\mu-\int 1_B\, d\mu\right| = \left|\int (1_A-1_B) d\mu\right|\leq\int 1_{A\Delta B}d\mu=\mu(A\Delta B),$$
where the integral makes sense because either $\mu(A)$ or $\mu(B)$ is finite. The inequality is the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A\subseteq B\cup \left( A\triangle B \right) $

and $B\subseteq A\cup \left( A\triangle B \right)$ and then by sub-aditive we have $${ m }^{ \ast  }\left( A \right) \le { m }^{ \ast  }\left( B \right) { +m }^{ \ast  }\left( A\triangle B \right) $$
$${ m }^{ \ast  }\left( B \right) \le { m }^{ \ast  }\left( A \right) { +m }^{ \ast  }\left( A\triangle B \right) $$ by first inequality
$${ m }^{ \ast  }\left( A \right) -{ m }^{ \ast  }\left( B \right) \le { m }^{ \ast  }\left( A\triangle B \right)  $$ and by second inequality we have $$-{ m }^{ \ast  }\left( A\triangle B \right) \le { m }^{ \ast  }\left( A \right) -{ m }^{ \ast  }\left( B \right) $$